# Laravel Connection Stopped working

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a local Laravel site installed and it was working fine and now it's throwing a DB connection error. Here is the function it's failing on:

[image]

My local database is set up, the username is root and there is no password (or the password is blank) so that should work fine.

I'm getting an error:

```
PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

It doesn't make sense because it was working and as you can see, it's not even recognizing the 'root' username anymore.

I have a file named '.env' in the root of my whole installation and it has the right credentials as far as I know:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=my_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

And those are all correct.

Any ideas why this would stop working all of a sudden?

For more data, my app/config/database.php file is:

```
    'connections' => array(

    'sqlite' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'my_db',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    'pgsql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'my_db',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ),

    'sqlsrv' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'my_db',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

),
```

Comment: Try to set the password to `=''`

Comment: where is your database config file.?.paste here

Comment: @rmondesilva if you are referring to that in the .env file, that didn't work.

Comment: @JasmelPc, just posted that

Comment: Try restarting sql server from command line. For mysql - `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Comment: laravel 4 or laravel 5..?which version you are using?

Comment: I think some codes in the start of database.php is missing.can you please confirm?please paste the full code of that file.

Comment: @jitendrapurohit that didn't work

Comment: @JasmelPc version 4.1

Comment: @JasmelPc yes there is `'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS`, some comments and then `'default' => 'mysql',` in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Just [change the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) and do appropriate action in .env and database.php

Please dont use root without having password.after all this do a mysql restart and an apache restart.all the best. :)

Comment: This installation was previously working fine so it doesn't really answer my question. I'm trying to figure out why the site broke and why it would previously work and now does not. Thanks!